# Can I somehow use win+1 (2, 3, 4, 5..) to start applications in GNOME Shell's left-hand launcher?

Tags: gnome, shortcut-keys

Like in Unity. As simply as that.  =) Otherwise the left-hand-launcher (panel or whatever you would call it) would be quite useless to me.

Comment: Is it question or answer

Comment: windows + 1, 2 ... works in unity

Comment: He's wondering if there is any way to launch the applications from GNOME-Shell's application dock in the same manner as in Unity.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it through a [AutoKey](http://code.google.com/p/autokey/) (get it from [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~cdekter/+archive/ppa)). It allows You to bind any script to a hot key. Here's and example of script which You can bind to a hot key. It starts a `bash` script, which open emacs, starts a server, and then opens some other files in it,

```
import subprocess
subprocess.Popen(["/home/boris/Its/scripts/bk-starts/bk-starts-emacs.bash"])
```

here's a script to bring LibreOffice window:

```
window.activate("LibreOffice")
```

and so on!

Comment: Thanks!  Is this ressource-intensive?

Comment: Well - on pressing `Ctrl-Esc` it says me there that autokey-gtk takes 0 CPU, 23.244 K of Memory, 18.236 K of Sharded memory. I wouldn't say it is heavy. I don't feel wither I run it or not.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't, at least not yet. Here is the "Cheat sheet" for GNOME-Shell and at the bottom you find all the available keyboard shortcuts:

http://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/CheatSheet

You can also look through the mappable keyboard shortcuts in the system settings and see a complete list there.